# Subclassing UIBarButtonItem with touchesBegan action

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to create a sub class of `UIBarButtonItem` that I can use in Storyboards/Xibs where for the **touchesBegan** action can be listened (to play a button sound right on touching the buttons). Here's what I got:

```
class UIAudibleBarButtonItem : UIBarButtonItem {
    override init()     {
        super.init()
        target = self
        action = "touchesBegan:"
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder:NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func touchesBegan(touches:NSSet, withEvent event:UIEvent) {
        AudioManager.instance.playButtonSound()
    }
}
```

However it doesn't work, i.e. touchesBegan isn't called. What do I need to change to make this work?

UPDATE:

```
class UIAudibleBarButtonItem : UIBarButtonItem {
    override init() {
        super.init();
        setup();
    }

    override init(barButtonSystemItem systemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem, target: AnyObject?, action: Selector) {
        super.init(barButtonSystemItem: systemItem, target: target, action: action);
        setup();
    }

    override init(image: UIImage?, landscapeImagePhone: UIImage?, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle, target: AnyObject?, action: Selector) {
        super.init(image: image, landscapeImagePhone: landscapeImagePhone, style: style, target: target, action: action);
        setup();
    }

    override init(image: UIImage?, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle, target: AnyObject?, action: Selector) {
        super.init(image: image, style: style, target: target, action: action);
        setup();
    }


    override init(title: String?, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle, target: AnyObject?, action: Selector) {
        super.init(title: title, style: style, target: target, action: action);
        setup();
    }

    override init(customView:UIView) {
        super.init(customView: customView);
        setup();
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder:NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder);
        setup();
    }


    private func setup()
    {
        target = self;
        action = "buttonPressed:";
        println("setup()");
    }


    func buttonPressed(sender:AnyObject)
    {
        AudioManager.instance.playButtonSound();
        println("buttonPressed()");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hitest and check which view is handling the touch.

Answer (score 3):

If your using swift here's an easy way to detect actions below. All you have to do is hook up that class in your storyboard click on your bar button item you will see the action fire.

Thank me later!!!

```
class MVBarbuttonItem: UIBarButtonItem {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.action = #selector(MVBarbuttonItem.didTapButton)
    }

    @objc func didTapButton() {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're giving `UIAudibleBarButtonItem` as a custom class in storyboard rather put this line right above your class `@objc(UIAudibleBarButtonItem)` and then see if it works.

This is what worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

`UIBarButtonItem` isn't a `UIView`.

If you'd like to achieve something like this, create a button, listen to touch on that button ( with `addTarget:...` or `touchesBegan` ) and use the `initWithCustomView` to create your bar button item from that button.

Edit:

Depending on when exactly the sound should be played, there is another possibility. If you want to play the sound after press and release, just modify your above code into this :

`action = "buttonPressed:" 
...
func buttonPressed(sender:AnyObject)`

Comment: But that only works programatically? Not applicable in Storyboards/Xib files, right?

Comment: @Avalon see my edit. If you need to play the sound instantly as the user touches the button, you need to do the hard way.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but it doesn't work. buttonPressed() doesn't get called. How is this different anyway from my code above, other than that the handler name is different?

EDIT: Actually the initializer doesn't get called at all. But the coder init gets called! But even after putting the two lines into the coder init, it doesn't work.

Comment: It's not too much difference, it has the correct number of parameters only. Does the `action = "buttonPressed:"` line execute ? Edit : then put those two target and action lines in the other init too ( or create a `commonInit` function and call that from both inits )

Comment: Ok, I overrid everyone of the initializers, just to be sure and the common init method gets definitely called when I test it. But the buttonPressed never gets called. see also my updated code above.